# Files in the same directory seen differently by different tools

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs, cygwin, chocolatey

I have installed chocolate(packet manager) programs at:

`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin`

And also installed fzf(search tool) as GVIM plugin.Accidently installed at the same dir: 
 `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin`

There is weird situation where different tools see different files in this dir:

- `cmd.exe` - see fzf.vim files
- `cmder.exe` - see choco files
- `explorer` - see choco files
- `totalcmd.exe` -see fzf.vim files
- `nerdtree(gvim)` - see `chocolatey/bin` as one name and there are
  fzf.vim files

I have installed Cygwin and Gow(linux commands at Win) projects at my Windows 7 64bit with NTFS partition.
Does it have a connection with path that sometime is typed in "linux way" using `/` insted `\`?

I had similar situation with some Cygwin dir before.

Comment: Hint: File Permissions.

Comment: This is due to the way Windows protects itself from programs that attempt to modify administrator protected locations as non-administrator applications.